# How to correctly expose ports for the Parastate node?

Tags: blockchain

Parastate node requires exposing ports.
30333: Default p2p traffic port. Make sure you expose this port externally.
9933: Default RPC traffic port.
9944: Default WebSocket traffic port.

After I enable ufw on ubuntu and run
$sudo ufw allow 30333
However, when I check here https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ whether ports are opened I get an answer it is still closed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I used ufw for that purpose:

```
sudo ufw enabl
sudo ufw allow 30333
sudo ufw allow 9933
sudo ufw allow 9944
```

And check whether it worked:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Don't forget to start your node before checking ports here: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 0):

try to use nmap to check your ports? nmap 127.0.0.1 and if not open,try use iptables command to open your ports